# How to change MDRectangleFlatIconButton text colour in Kivy/KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy

I'm creating a layout using Kivy and KivyMD and wish to change the colour of the text displayed in the MD buttons, however the colour remains stuck on a light blue.

I've included an example of what I tried in the code below.

.py code

```
import kivy, kivymd

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager


class ButtonColorApp(App):

    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    title='RUCES'

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(IntroPage(name="intro_page"))
        return sm

class IntroPage(Screen):

    #funcs and vars
    pass

def main():
        but = ButtonColorApp()
        but.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

.kv code

```
#: import MDRectangleFlatIconButton kivymd.button.MDRectangleFlatIconButton
#: import MDLabel kivymd.label.MDLabel

<MyButton@MDRectangleFlatIconButton>:
    text_size: self.size * 3
    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
    font_size: 20
    md_bg_color: (0,0,.4,1)
    canvas.before:
       Color:
            rgba: (0,0,0,1)
            Line:
                width: 0.5
                rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)


<IntroPage>:

    BoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"

        MyButton:
            size_hint_x: 1
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text: "Colour Me!"
            text_color: (1,0,0,1)
```

When I run this I expect the button text to be red but as mentioned above it remains light blue. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

Currently, the text colour for *MDRectangleFlatIconButton* and *MDRoundFlatIconButton* widgets will always default to the `theme_cls.primary_color` even with attributes, `theme_text_color: 'Custom'` and `text_color: [1,0,0,1]`.

## Solution

The temporary solution is as follow:

1. In your kv file, replace import statement,
   `kivymd.button.MDRectangleFlatIconButton` with your customised
   *button.py* i.e. `button.MDRectangleFlatIconButton`
2. Either take a copy of *button.py* from [my GitHub](https://github.com/ikolim/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/button.py)
3. Or take a copy of *button.py* from `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivymd`, or `~/KivyMD` (created by `git clone https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git`), or download and extract KivyMD Zip file ([Download ZIP](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/archive/master.zip)) , and apply the following changes

Replace:

```
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: root.theme_cls.primary_color
```

with:

```
        theme_text_color: root.theme_text_color   
        text_color: root.text_color
```

### Snippets: button.py - kv

```
<MDRectangleFlatIconButton>
    ...
    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
    text_color: root.theme_cls.primary_color

    BoxLayout:
        ...

        MDIcon:
            ...

        MDLabel:
            ..
            theme_text_color: root.theme_text_color    
            text_color: root.text_color                 
            markup: root.markup

<MDRoundFlatIconButton>
    ...
    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
    text_color: root.theme_cls.primary_color

    BoxLayout:
        ...
        MDIcon:
            ...

        MDLabel:
            ...
            theme_text_color: root.theme_text_color     
            text_color: root.text_color                 
            markup: root.markup
```

## Output

[image: Result]

## [KivyMD GitHub](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution! I tried it, but I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.backgroundcolorbehavior'. Any idea why that happened? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to use markup language, e.g.:

1. in your `.kv` file assign `"id"` to your `MDButton`

```
MDFlatButton:

    id: info_btn
```

2. then in your `.py` file

```
self.ids.info_btn.text = '[color=#00ffcc]Info[/color]'

self.ids.info_btn.markup = True
```